# Map the cell to display JSON data in HTML table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, json

I want to display the JSON data of the cell by mapping the first row (dynamic - products) and column (Suppliers). This is the JSON input and the code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var json = [{
        "Supplier": "Supplier1",
        "Product": "Oxygen",
        "Quantity": 50
    }, {
        "Supplier": "Supplier1",
        "Product": "Hydrogen",
        "Quantity": 100
    }, {
        "Supplier": "Supplier1",
        "Product": "Carbon",
        "Quantity": 50
    }, {
        "Supplier": "Supplier2",
        "Product": "Carbon",
        "Quantity": 200
    }, {
        "Supplier": "Supplier2",
        "Product": "Oxygen",
        "Quantity": 100
    }, {
        "Supplier": "Supplier3",
        "Product": "Hydrogen",
        "Quantity": 50
    }];
    var tr;
    for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
        tr = $('<tr/>');
        tr.append("<td>" + json[i].Supplier + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + json[i].Product + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + json[i].Quantity + "</td>");
        $('table').append(tr);
    }
});
```

This is the table:

[image]

I want to rearrange the data to get this:

[image]

Map supplier and product, display the quantity. All are dynamic values.

Please Help.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Is it possible you can change the JSON you receive to better match the table format?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan In which format it should be?

Comment: An array of suppliers, that each contain an array of products.

Comment: @skubski How to bind it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I'm not familiar with jQuery, so I use the native JavaScript in some places.

If you can't access to the format from the server side, you may change your format on client side, like below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var json = [{
        "Supplier": "Supplier1",
        "Product": "Oxygen",
        "Quantity": 50
    }, {
        "Supplier": "Supplier1",
        "Product": "Hydrogen",
        "Quantity": 100
    }, {
        "Supplier": "Supplier1",
        "Product": "Carbon",
        "Quantity": 50
    }, {
        "Supplier": "Supplier2",
        "Product": "Carbon",
        "Quantity": 200
    }, {
        "Supplier": "Supplier2",
        "Product": "Oxygen",
        "Quantity": 100
    }, {
        "Supplier": "Supplier3",
        "Product": "Hydrogen",
        "Quantity": 50
    }];

    var data = {}; // reformat the data
    var products = []; // types of products

    json.forEach(function(entry) {
        if (!data.hasOwnProperty(entry.Supplier)) {
            data[entry.Supplier] = {};
        }

        if (data[entry.Supplier].hasOwnProperty(entry.Product)) {
            data[entry.Supplier][entry.Product] += entry.Quantity;
        } else {
            data[entry.Supplier][entry.Product] = entry.Quantity;
        }

        // add new product type
        if (products.indexOf(entry.Product) === -1) {
            products.push(entry.Product);
        }
    });

    // set <th> line
    $('table').append('<tr><th>Supplier</th><th>' +
        products.join('</th><th>') +
        '</th></tr>');

    var table_str = '';

    for (entry in data) {
        if (data.hasOwnProperty(entry)) {
            table_str += '<tr>';
            table_str += '<td>' + entry + '</td>';
            products.forEach(function(product) {
                if (data[entry].hasOwnProperty(product)) {
                    table_str += '<td>' + data[entry][product] + '</td>';
                } else {
                    table_str += '<td></td>';
                }
            });
            table_str += '</tr>';
        }
    }

    $('table').append(table_str);

    console.log(data);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table></table>
```

Comment: Thanks alot :) This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

you can do this using simple logic as well.

you need to just sort your json based on supplier. then get all available product from json data.

and logic will be do rest of the thing.

here is working jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/jdk2f7gr/

**javascript code**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   var json = [{
        "Supplier": "Supplier1",
        "Product": "Oxygen",
        "Quantity": 50
    }, {
        "Supplier": "Supplier1",
        "Product": "Hydrogen",
        "Quantity": 100
    }, {
        "Supplier": "Supplier1",
        "Product": "Carbon",
        "Quantity": 50
    }, {
        "Supplier": "Supplier2",
        "Product": "Carbon",
        "Quantity": 200
    }, {
        "Supplier": "Supplier2",
        "Product": "Oxygen",
        "Quantity": 100
    }, {
        "Supplier": "Supplier3",
        "Product": "Hydrogen",
        "Quantity": 50
    },
    {
        "Supplier": "Supplier3",
        "Product": "Nitrogon",
        "Quantity": 200
    }];

    function sortResults(prop, asc) {
        json = json.sort(function(a, b) {
        if (asc) return (a[prop] > b[prop]) ? 1 : ((a[prop] < b[prop]) ? -1 : 0);
        else return (b[prop] > a[prop]) ? 1 : ((b[prop] < a[prop]) ? -1 : 0);
        });

    }
    sortResults('Supplier',true);

    var tr;
    var supName=json[0].Supplier;
    var productList=$.unique(json.map(function (d) {
    return d.Product;}));

    var prod={};
    function appendHeader(productList){
        tr = $('<tr/>');
        tr.append("<th>Supplier</th>");
        for(var i=0;i < productList.length; i++)
            {               
                    tr.append("<th>" + productList[i] + "</th>");           
            }
            $('table').append(tr);      
    }
    appendHeader(productList);

    function appendRow(supName,prod){
        tr = $('<tr/>');
            tr.append("<td>" + supName + "</td>");
            for(var i=0;i < productList.length; i++)
            {
                if (prod[productList[i]]) {
                    tr.append("<td>" + prod[productList[i]] + "</td>");
                } else {
                    tr.append("<td></td>");
                }

            }


            $('table').append(tr);
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {

        if(supName===json[i].Supplier){
            if(prod[json[i].Product]){
              prod[json[i].Product]= prod[json[i].Product] + json[i].Quantity;
            }else{
                 prod[json[i].Product]=json[i].Quantity;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            appendRow(supName,prod);
            prod={};
            supName=json[i].Supplier;
             if(prod[json[i].Product]){
              prod[json[i].Product]= prod[json[i].Product] + json[i].Quantity;
            }else{
                 prod[json[i].Product]=json[i].Quantity;
            }
        }


    }
    appendRow(supName,prod);

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just use AJAX to return JSON based on the parameter you pass through.
This will allow you to customise it.

The other way would be to take the: 
Supplier1 etc and add them to a seperate array that would contain Product and Quantity.
Then itterate through them and add based on the position in thead that the Product appear.

Such as, I am on supplier2, I have product Carbon. Check thead for position Carbon appeaers. Add val to current col in row.

```
function findAjax() {
                $.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  dataType: 'json',
                  url: '/Action/GetDynamicJson?format='$('#json-format').val(),
                  success: function(response){              
                        $('#table-container').html("");
                        $.each (response, function (index) {
                          if ($('#json-format').val() = '1'){
                            var tableRow = "";
                            tableRow = $('<tr/>');
                            tableRow.append("<td>" + response[index].Supplier + "</td>");
                            tableRow.append("<td>" + response[index].Product + "</td>");
                            tableRow.append("<td>" + response[index].Quantity + "</td>");
                            $('#table-container').append(tableRow);
                          }else{
                          }
                  });  
                  },
                  error: function(req, status, error) {
                      //console.log("findAjax "+ status+" "+error);
                  }
              });
};
```